# Update table with combined field from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with actions that are being due in the future. I have a second table that holds all the cases, including the due date of the case. And I have a third table that holds numbers.

The problems is as follows. Our system automatically populates our table with future actions. For some clients however, we need to change these dates. I wanted to create an update query for this, and have this run through our scheduler. However, I am kind of stuck at the moment.

What I have on code so far is this:

```
UPDATE proxima_gestion p 
SET    fecha = (SELECT To_char(d.f_ult_vencim + c.hrem01, 'yyyyMMdd') 
                FROM   deuda d, 
                       c4u_activity_dates c, 
                       proxima_gestion p 
                WHERE  d.codigo_cliente = c.codigo_cliente 
                       AND p.n_expediente = d.n_expediente 
                       AND d.saldo > 1000 
                       AND p.tipo_gestion_id = 914 
                       AND p.codigo_oficina = 33 
                       AND d.f_ult_vencim > sysdate) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   proxima_gestion p, 
                      deuda d 
               WHERE  p.n_expediente = d.n_expediente 
                      AND d.saldo > 1000 
                      AND p.tipo_gestion_id = 914 
                      AND p.codigo_oficina = 33 
                      AND d.f_ult_vencim > sysdate)
```

The field fecha is the current action date. Unfortunately, this is saved as a char instead of date. That is why I need to convert the date back to a char. F_ult_vencim is the due date, and hrem01 is the number of days the actions should be placed away from the due date. (for example, this could be 10, making the new date 10 days after the due date)

Apart from that, there are a few more criteria when we need to change the date (certain creditors, certain departments, only for future cases and starting from a certain amount, only for a certain action type.)

However, when I try and run this query, I get the error message
    ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

If I run both subqueries seperately, I get 2 results from both. What I am trying to accomplish, is that it connects these 2 queries, and updates the field to the new value. This value will be different for every case, as every due date will be different.

Is this even possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Do you have an ID field in your proxima_gestion table that you can JOIN/MERGE on?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the first SELECT is returning more than one row for each row in the table being updated.

The first thing I see is that the alias for the table in UPDATE is the same as the alias in both SELECTs (p).  So all of the references to p in the subqueries are referencing proxima_gestion **in the subquery** rather than the outer query.  That is, the subquery is not dependent on the outer query, which is required for an UPDATE.

Try removing "proxima_gestion p" from FROM in both subqueries.  The references to p, then, will be to the outer UPDATE query.